# html text scaling on chrome browser: strange character limit

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm learning how to make a web page and started off with a simple page displaying the word "Hello". When I view it in Chrome Browser (version 44.0.2403.122), the text CANNOT BE SCALED with "Settings->Accessibility->Text Scaling". And that's the problem, I think the ability to scale shouldn't be taken from the user if the text has only a couple of characters.

However, when I display more than a certain number of characters, scaling eventually works (see example below).

Is there some logic or magic about character limits I'm not aware of?

Thanks for your help!

Scaling DOES NOT work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Hello.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Scaling DOES work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants. Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, bla bla b</p>

</body>
</html>
```

If I delete the last character "b" in the previous paragraph, scaling DOES NOT work. Strange, huh?